# Get part of className using JQuery returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I have this piece of code in codesandbox, but its returning null when i try to get part of className from div using JQuery. How can i make it work?

[Codesandbox Code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-gates-etbi9)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import $ from "jquery";

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $(".MainContainer").on("mousedown", function(evt) {
      $(".MainContainer").on("mouseup mousemove", function handler(evt) {
        alert(
          $(this)
            .attr("class")
            .match(/\bsizes[^\s]+\b/)
        );
      });
    });
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="MainContainer sizes" />;
  }
}
```

The css class:

```
.MainContainer {
  background: #282c34;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code (as a [mcve]) here on StackOverflow, in the question

Comment: `alert($(this).hasClass("sizes"));`

Comment: I need to return the className not true or false.

Comment: Waiting for the hounds to arrive saying not to use jQuery in react.... (guess I am the first)

Comment: Not sure how that [reg exp](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5Cbsizes%5B%5E%5Cs%5D%2B%5Cb%2F) is to match "sizes" `"foo sizes".match(/\bsizes[^\s]+\b/)` is null since there is nothing after sizes...

Comment: https://regexr.com/  write proper regexp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I highly recommend to not use jQuery with your react code, but if you have to, then use `ref` utility to handle dom events and let React handles them, instead of directly involving jQuery.

In addition to using multiple events for `on()` method, pass an object with multiple methods instead of nesting them.

I propose using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` method to retrieve any data or DOM elements to prevent mistakes.

Finally I commented your regex to see it works or not. The regex is returning null but the rest of the code is working.

[View on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-architecture-24t2s)

**PS:** React way is following.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import $ from "jquery";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $(this.myRef.current).on({
      mousedown: function(evt) {
        console.log(
          $(this).attr("class")
          // .match(/\bsizes[^\s]+\b/)
        );
      },
      mouseup: function(evt) {
        console.log(
          $(this).attr("class")
          // .match(/\bsizes[^\s]+\b/)
        );
      },
      mousemove: function(evt) {
        console.log(
          $(this).attr("class")
          // .match(/\bsizes[^\s]+\b/)
        );
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="MainContainer sizes" ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

**The React Way**

As I recommended to use only react for handling DOM elements, I'll post the React code, too.

**Note:** I made a loop through the events but you can just repeat events by hand to decrease complexity. Also, I used `find()` to loop trough `DOMTokenList` values and checked them to match the regex. I commented that line to prevent the response of the regex checking.

[View on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-fog-rxj45)

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.eventHandler();
  }

  eventHandlerCallback = e => {
    console.log(
      Object.values(e.target.classList)
      // .find(item => item.match(/\bsizes[^\s]+\b/))
    );
  };

  eventHandler = () => {
    const events = ["mousedown", "mouseup", "mousemove"];
    events.map(e =>
      this.myRef.current.addEventListener(e, this.eventHandlerCallback)
    );
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="MainContainer sizes" ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not show the *React way*? Clearly OP is in the progress of moving from library to library.

Comment: I'll update the answer with the React way. Thanks for reminding :)